# Mongodb: Specify field data type, collection _id to be datetime

Tags: javascript, mongodb, datetime, field

I have a collection whose _id objects should be a datetime.

The collection is updated  in javascript and performs an aggregation for a specific time.

```
  var aggregated = { '_id': new Date()};
  ... do work to aggregated ...
  updateDB.save(aggregated);
```

How do I specify that my _id object should of type datetime.  More generally, how do I specify that a field should be a particular type.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

MongoDB is a schemaless and heterogeneous database. Any field of a document (including `_id`) can be of any type. There is no way to enforce type constraints on the database level.

Comment: Interesting. I use MongoVUE to examine our collections. In many of the collections, the _id type is shown as a DateTime object. Similarly, when I export these collections, the output of the _id field is a date object. This is not the case in my new collections.  Counfing my issues is that the aggregation javascript is nearly identical to existing scripts which produce the datetime.

Comment: Nearly identical is not identical. Found my issue. Thanks again.